# Convert Equation Editor Equation to Plain Text?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, equation-editor

I have a Word Document with some text and Equation Editor equations that needs to be pasted into AutoCAD. AutoCAD doesn't support Equation Editor (or LaTex) objects in a MTEXT field.

Is there a way to convert an Equation Editor object back to plain text, or do these need to be retyped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the equation container and paste it into Notepad... the container is removed and the equation is then converted into a linear plain text format.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing (except with Atom)